# Get the whole image with out scrolling in javascript, canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Consider the following:

[image]

All of what you see is rendered on to a HTML 5 canvas. As you can see this image scrolls. As the character walks around the map will scroll around.

Consider the actual image:

[image]

This image is the actual image of the map the character walks on. Now consider the following code:

```
class MapExporter {

  static exportCurrentMap() {
    var imageInformation = Bitmap.snap(SceneManager._scene)._context.canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    var splitInformationFromImage = imageInformation.split(',');
    var atobInformation = atob(splitInformationFromImage[1]);
    var atobInformationLength = atobInformation.length;
    var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(atobInformationLength);

    for (var i = 0; i < atobInformationLength; i++) {
      uint8Array[i] = atobInformation.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    var blobData = new Blob([uint8Array], {type: 'image/png'});
    saveAs.saveAs(blobData, 'map.png');
  }
}
```

This code, when run creates the following image:

[image]

The code works, but as you can see we only grab the current visible image from the canvas. Now the way this is all rendered uses Pixi.js, so my question is:

**Is there a way to get the WHOLE image WITHOUT scrolling?**

Does the canvas api have anything like this? The only other way is to scroll and stitch, but I have no idea how to do that, I can make it scroll but I don't know when to stop, or how to stitch.

So I am hoping there is something that allows me to just get all non visible elements

Comment: I'm not *so* experienced with canvas, but to further clarify; it sounds like what you're looking for is something like that famous 100%-seamless, super-huge image of the Pokémon world map, right? Kind of an interesting goal, but it really may have to involve somehow hitching itself into the engine's main draw function, to provide an alternate draw target from the visible canvas itself.

Comment: Probably part of the reason I doubt the canvas has direct "draw outside itself" capability is that many game engines tend not to *actually* draw those areas. Simply-coded games usually do because there's no perceived performance hit, but in many engines for efficiency, the draw method will only find the entities that are actually inside the camera's view for drawing, and ignore any others.

Comment: Simply using the standard [`.drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) will work. As you can draw an entire image on the canvas, past the canvas bounds. Note that it will automatically clip the parts past the canvas on each render based on the bounds (*for performance reason, all computer graphics renders do this*). But it will draw the entire image as in *if* you could move the canvas over it will be there. If you want to show more in one view you simply will need a larger canvas.

Comment: as @SpencerWieczorek told you, you just need to draw your stage on a larger canvas element. Now, to get the character and all other objects positions, you'll need to get access to these properties while exporting, and redraw the whole scene on the larger export canvas.

Comment: Easiest would be to find the tile maps and tile images and then just reconstruct the maps separate from the game. By the looks its a very simple map and highly likely that the tiles data is just a 2D array of indexes. If I knew the name of the game I could have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/q61hb9yf/1

```
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var Player = function (xSet, ySet) {
    this.XPos = xSet;
    this.YPos = ySet;
    this.Color = "#0F0";
}

var Background = function (xSet, ySet) {
    this.XPos = xSet;
    this.YPos = ySet;
    this.Sprite = new Image();
    this.Sprite.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcFJb.png";
}

var player = new Player(343, 343);
var background = new Background(0, 0);

function moveSomething(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            if (background.XPos < 0) {
            background.XPos += 48;
            }
            else{
                player.XPos -= 48;
            }
            break;
        case 38:
            if (background.YPos < 0) {
                background.YPos += 48;
            } else {
                player.YPos -= 48;
            }
            break;
        case 39:
            if (Math.abs(background.XPos) < (c.width / 2)) {
                background.XPos -= 48;
            } else {
                player.XPos += 48;
            }
            break;
        case 40:
            if (Math.abs(background.YPos) < (c.height / 2)) {
                background.YPos -= 48;
            } else {
                player.YPos += 48;
            }
            break;
    }
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", moveSomething, false);



setInterval(function () {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.drawImage(background.Sprite, background.XPos, background.YPos);
    ctx.fillStyle = player.Color;
    ctx.fillRect(player.XPos, player.YPos, 48, 48);
}, 3)
```

This will draw out the whole image onto the canvas and allow the user to use the arrow keys to move around, there is no collision detection.

Comment: A little explanation of how it does this ? Also, it seems OP just needs to export the whole stage, but keep playing on the scrolling one.